# Word VBA - Save Multiple Files

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi I have a word file that makes a change to a table using VBA. After every change, I would like to save a new file with these changes. This way I have 10 copies with 10 different tables.

But currently, when I perform the code below, it exits the original, and thereby exiting the loop. Excel has a method SaveCopyAs, which Word doesn't have. Are there any ways to workaround this?

> Documents.Add.SaveAs2 FileName:=("C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\Baby
>   Shower Table Games_Updated_" & x & ".docm")

Comment: Using `If Dir(filepath)`, you could keep appending Copy to the end of the file until there's no file named `filepath` found.

Comment: Or even sum + 1 at a index sufix on the pathfile.

Comment: You don't need the .add. Just be aware that each time you save the document the document name is updated to match the filename you have just used for saving so if you want to retain your original filename, save the .name in a variable and then do a final .saveas2 using .name to restore your original filename (although the file will be the final edited version)

Comment: I’m sorry Lodi, but I’m not sure I understand this quite yet. Would it be possible for you to clarify how this would save a new file without closing the active document?

Comment: I edited my question seeing that the old question wasn’t conveying my problem effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below demonstrates what you need to know.

```
Sub test()

Dim my_doc                      As Word.Document
Dim my_index                    As Long
Dim my_initial_name             As String

    Set my_doc = ActiveDocument

    my_initial_name = my_doc.FullName

    For my_index = 1 To 10
        '<OTHER ACTIONS BEFORE SAVING>
        my_doc.SaveAs2 FileName:="C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\Baby Shower Table Games_Updated_" & CStr(my_index) & ".docm"
    Next

    my_doc.SaveAs2 FileName:=my_initial_name

End Sub
```

Comment: After the first my_doc.SaveAs2, the vba code stops running, and Word hangs when executing the second my_doc.SaveAs2. This appears to be doing the same thing as my code + Word hanging up.

Comment: Works fine on my pc. You WILL need to edit the file path to one that actually exists on your PC.

Comment: Thanks @Freeflow I really appreciate your help. My error was elsewhere that was causing the file to be stuck in an infinite loop, but your code does the trick to save files like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shoud use `FileCopy` instead `.SaveAs`.